# In abstract algebra, does the existence of a multiplicative inverse in a ring mean that there is a multiplicative identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I just learned some abstract algebra today, so I’m a little shaky with the definitions. I know that a multiplicative inverse is defined based on the multiplicative identity ($g*g'= e$ where $e$ is the multiplicative identity, $g$ is any element, and $g'$ is the multiplicative inverse), so does that mean that there must be a multiplicative identity if there is a multiplicative inverse? Or am I oversimplifying this?

Comment: Yes, in general, for _any_ set $S$ with _any_ binary operation $*$, it makes sense to talk about inverses (with respect to $*$) only when $*$ has an identity.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks!

Comment: Also, you only wrote "$g * g' = e$" and said that $g'$ is the inverse of $g$. Note that for it to be the inverse, it must satisfy the property that $g * g' = e = g' * g$. (Which would be forced automatically if $*$ is _commutative_ but not necessarily otherwise.)

Comment: It would be hard to say what an inverse is if you do not have an identity but a similar property which does not require an identity is the cancellation property.  Can you deduce $x = y$ from $ax = yx$?

Comment: @badjohn um, do you mean "can you deduce $a = y$ from $a x = y x$?" ?

Comment: @PrimeMover Sorry, typing mistake.  I intended to say deduce $x=y$ from $ax= ay$.  In some rings you can't but in others you can even though there is no identity or inverses.  (For $a \neq 0$ of course.)

Comment: The definition of a multiplicative inverse presupposes the existence of an identity. However, even if you rewrite the axiom in a way that avoids mentioning the identity (by only having division), its existence still follows, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3474093/30222 (this is as long as you have two-sided division; I believe that in a non-commutative ring, you might have one-sided division without having identity; I'm not sure, though).

Comment: In rings, $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$ for any $x$ and $y$ if and only if there does not exist $b\neq 0$ such that $ab=0$. That is: $a$ is cancellable on the left if and only if it is not a left zero divisor.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Yes . . . with a caveat.

It is possible to define an associative binary operation $\ast$ on a set $S$ such that for all $a\in S$, there exists a $b\in S$ such that

$$a*b*a=a\quad\text{and}\quad b*a*b=b.$$

No identity is necessary in this case.

See [inverse semigroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup#:%7E:text=In%20group%20theory%2C%20an%20inverse,element%20has%20a%20unique%20inverse.) for example.

Comment: Good job, yes I caught sight of this when I was exploring the subject some years back, and I was going to look for it. Well done for finding it.

Comment: Though these elements are sometimes, especially outside of semigroup theory where the terminology is well-entrenched, called "pseudoinverses" rather than inverses (e.g., the Moore-Penrose  pseudoinverse for matrices).

Comment: Thank you, @PrimeMover. It's not so much a "find", more just something I was taught. My MMath dissertation was on inverse semigroups.

Comment: @Shaun Didn't do much formal ab alg in my own MMath beyond group theory. My own diss was on aspects of the 4 colour thm. Hey ho.

Answer (score 1):

If you take 'inverse' to mean, "Can I solve the equation $x\cdot y=z$ for any one of the variables if I know two of them?" then, assuming the multiplication is associative (since you are working in a ring), an identity element must exist.

Fix $x\neq 0$ and let $y$ denote the solution to $x\cdot y=x$. Then for any $z$, taking $y'$ so that $y'\cdot x=z$, we have: $$z\cdot y=(y'\cdot x)\cdot y=y'\cdot(x\cdot y)=y'\cdot x=z$$
i.e. our first $y$ is a right-sided identity element. Similarly, we can construct a left-sided identity element $w$ (that is, $w\cdot z=z$ for every $z$). Then $y=w$ because $w=w\cdot y=y$, because $w$ is a left-sided identity element and $y$ is a right-sided identity element. Hence, there exists a unique two-sided identity element.

If you work on a more general setting, where you still assume the cancellative property of the first paragraph, but do not have associativity, then an identity element need not exist, and such structures (ignoring the ring additivity as well) are called [quasigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).